# font styles not working in meteor when retrieved from db

Tags: meteor, meteorite

I am collecting the values from text area of a form and inserted them into a collection. But when i tried to display them in another template from the db, the styles are not getting applied.

Suppose if i have inserted **Android Programmer** in the database it is displaying 'Android Programmer' with the bold tags when i retrieved.

I am using bootstrap3-wysihtml5 richtext editor in my form.

What is the solution to avoid this problem.?My sample code here...

```
Jobs = new Meteor.Collection('jobs');

Template.postSubmit.events({
        'click .formsubmit': function(event){
            if(Meteor.user())
            {
            jobdescription = $('#jobDescription').val();
            Jobs.insert({
            J_Description:jobdescription;
            });
          }
       });

<template name="jobPage">
<div class="jobDetailBody">
    <p class="desc">{{J_Description}}</p>
</div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

When displaying the text from db i made use of handlebars. So the solution in this case is

```
<template name="jobPage">
<div class="jobDetailBody">
    <p class="desc">{{{J_Description}}}</p>
</div>
</template>
```

Just add three curly braces to the handle bars for which you want to escape html.